Outside the theory of relations is the term *converse* (of a mapping) ever used in place of *inverse*? (Opinionish)
One of the "gotchas" frequently found in mathematical literature is to ask the student to state something about the inverse of a mapping when the mapping is not invertible.  That is, when the mapping is not injective.  In the theory of relations, a mapping is a two-place relation which can be expressed as a set of ordered pairs with first components in the first domain (AKA domain) and second components in the second domain (AKA co-domain).  The inverse of a mapping is the two place relation formed by reversing those ordered pairs.
The term "inverse" is used in two mutually inconsistent ways which require further subtle qualification.

One way is the so-called inverse mapping.  In order for the inverse mapping to exist, the forward mapping must be injective; that is, it must be one-to-one.
The other way is the so-called inverse (image) of a mapping, which is (the first domain of) the relation formed by inverting the order of the pairs defining the "forward" mapping.  In terms of relations, this is called the converse relation.

For every mapping there is an inverse of the mapping which may or may not be an inverse mapping. Given that the standard terminology has this feature (bug), it is important for the student to understand and guard against this pitfall. Hence there is some justification for trick questions, etc.
I contend that the victim of this pitfall is less at fault than is the mathematical establishment who propagate this unnecessarily confusing language.
It seems advisable to use the term converse when discussing such entities as the so-called inverse image of a mapping.  That is; we should say converse image for the inverted set of ordered pairs. The term inverse image should be reserved for the image of an inverse mapping.
I am aware that the term pre-image is also used to specify what I am calling the converse image.  This, in my opinion, is superior to the term inverse image, but is not as widely applicable.
In order to turn this post into a question I will ask:
Outside of the theory of relations, is the term *converse* used as I am suggesting in mathematical literature?
